# Call a command within a listener

Tags: symfony, events, command, listener

I have a pretty complex command (not written by me) in my symfony API to send notifications, and I would like to have it run everytime a `PostPersist` event happens.

For this, I've set up a listener triggered by the `PostPersist` event and this part works perfectly. However, I can't manage to launch the command. I first tried to launch it like I did in a controller with the following piece of code:

```
$kernel = $this->get('kernel');
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);

$input = new ArrayInput(array(
    'command' => 'acme:send-notifications',
));
// You can use NullOutput() if you don't need the output
$output = new NullOutput();
$application->run($input, $output);
return new Response("");
```

but of course, it doesn't work in a Listener, since I can't get the kernel
So I tried to add the command to the services:

```
command.send-notifications:
    class: WD\ApiBundle\Command\SendNotificationsCommand
    tags:
        - { name: 'console.command', command: 'acme:send-notifications' }
```

and then call it this way:

```
$output = new NullOutput();
$this->sendNotifCommand->execute(null, $output);
```

but then I get the following error message:
`The container cannot be retrieved as the application instance is not yet set.`

I have to admit I don't quite understand what it means. Also, I must confess this part of symfony (listeners, commands) are quite new to me and I don't even know if I'm doing it the right way, or if there is a better system to send notifications everytime a persist happens in a specific entity...

Comment: Best option woul dbe to put the domain code called in your command in a service and use it. If you can, you can still the kernel in your listener

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it in a listener but you can try to launch your command with a Process :

```
$process = new Process("cd " . $this->projectDir . "; php bin/console YOUR_COMMAND_NAME");
$process->start();
```